# why does docker-compose up remove other running conainters?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I built a docker image and launched a container using the `docker-compose up` command.  I then modified the container and did a `docker commit` command.  When I try starting a container with the newly created image, it starts the new container but destroys the old container.  When i next try to boot up the old container it destroys new container and starts the old container.  I'm very confused.  Should docker/docker-compose be doing this?

the command i'm running

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d
```

The docker-compose file ($IMAGE_NAME and $CONTAINER_NAME are different for starting both the old and new container)

```
version: '2'                                                                                                                       
services:
  yolo:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: $IMAGE_NAME
    container_name: $CONTAINER_NAME
    ports:                      
      - "$EXTERNAL_SSH_PORT:22"
```

docker version:

```
docker --version
Docker version 1.12.3, build 6b644ec
```

docker-compose version:

```
docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.9.0, build 2585387
```

Comment: tl;dr: put them in different directories!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my issue was related to this:

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3472

notably:

> @kachkaev This isn't a bug, and has nothing to do with caching.
>
> Both your directories are named the same thing (docker), so when you
>   run docker-compose up in either directory you're working on the same
>   project. Each time you're updating the configuration of the same
>   service (web) to change both the image name and container name.
>
> It looks like what you actually want is two separate apps, each with
>   its own image and container. In that case, I suggest doing the
>   following:
>
> Either rename each directory so they're different or use the
>   --project-name option or COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME environment variable to set a different project name for each app. For example, myappdev and
>   myappprod. Remove the container_name option from both Compose files -
>   it's unnecessary. If you run docker-compose up in both directories,
>   you should now have two containers: myappdev_web and myappprod_web.